# Bash command to delete all but one file from a directory

Tags: bash

I have a backup folder that contains multiple MySQL backups with standard filenames that are derived from the time the backup was taken:

```
Jims-MBP-2:manual-1 jim$ ls -1
site-name-2011-02-12T19-04-13.mysql
site-name-2011-02-12T19-11-58.mysql
site-name-2011-02-12T19-22-50.mysql
site-name-2011-02-12T19-24-46.mysql
site-name-2011-02-13T14-30-42.mysql
```

Is there a one-line bash command that will delete all but the most recent backup?

Answer (score 3):

```
ls | grep -v $(ls -t | head -1) | xargs rm
```

Better:

```
ls -rt | tail -n +2 | xargs rm
```

Armoured against crazy filenames (everything except those with newlines in), suitable for use by paranoids:

```
ls -rt | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: @Juliano: parsing ls is absolutely fine. Worrying about filenames with newlines and other freaky characters in is a complete and utter waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
files='sitename*.mysql'
newest=($files)
for f in $files
do
    if [[ "$f" -nt "$newest" ]]
    then
        newest=$f
    fi
done
echo rm !("$newest")
```

You should [avoid parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to delete all of the backup files - any idea how I might be able to modify it so that all but the most recent backup are deleted?

Comment: @Jim: That does delete all but the newest file (of course the `echo` has to be removed). Add `echo "$newest"` at the end to see which file it's retaining. I'm editing to make a small change for consistency. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: A for-in-loop puts up very much the same problems as parsing ls - particularly when you forget to quote $f ;)

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Which `$f` do you mean? If you mean in the assignment `newest=$f` it doesn't need quoting there. When you do the `for` loop the way I have it, it's using globbing since `$files` is unquoted. Globbing works well with spaces in filenames. If I had set `files` to the actual list of files rather than to a glob-spec, then it would have the same problems as parsing `ls`. As I have it, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `extglob` option enabled:

```
rm !(`ls -1 site-name-*.mysql | sort -r | head -1`)
```

Comment: That works fine when I run it from the bash prompt, but when I run it from within a bash script I get the following error message - line 52: syntax error near unexpected token `(' - any idea as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output... *Sigh*

Comment: @Juliano: I agree, that's a good advice (similar to "don't parse HTML with regular expressions"). But sometimes it's relatively safe - as long as you're not parsing `ls -l` (to get files' stats) and you know your input (you're sure that filenames don't contain newlines). Sure - I could have pointed @Jim to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099. But he asked for *one-line bash command*.

Comment: @Jim: You have to enable `extglob` to make it work. (Take a look at Dennis Williamson example; the simplest way is to put `shopt -s extglob` before).